# How to retrive specific data from Mongodb

Tags: mongodb, express, mern

This is my data collection which are in MongoDB and I want to retrieve data of the model attribute.

```
{"_id":{"$oid":"61dd83fce198010f26b2f47d"},"assetID":"0001","assetCategory":"Laptop","model":"Asus","serialNumber":"0x001","status":"Non-Available","__v":{"$numberInt":"0"}}
```

I wrote my code like the below code segment by using express js.

```
router.get("/detail/:id",async(req,res)=>{
let ID = req.params.id;
await Asset.find({_id:ID}).then((assets)=>{
    res.json(assets)
}).catch((err)=>{
    console.log(err)
})
```

})

After that, I was able to get a json object like this.

```
[
{
    "_id": "61dd83fce198010f26b2f47d",
    "assetID": "0001",
    "assetCategory": "Laptop",
    "model": "Asus",
    "serialNumber": "0x001",
    "status": "Non-Available",
    "__v": 0
}
```

]

But I want to get only a data of model attribute. Can anyone please explain what are the changes that I should do? Thank you!

Comment: Not exactly sure what you are asking.  Do you only want the `model` attribute to be returned or you want to find by `model` and not `_id`?

Comment: @BuzzMoschetti Actually I want to get only model attributes from these data. If you can see my JSON objects, there are various data of, such as assetID, assetCategory and so on. I want only data of model attribute. In this json object, it can be represented as "model":"Asus"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
await Asset.find({_id:ID},{model:true}).then((assets)=>{
```

The second arg to `find()` is the projection, the equivalent of `select model ..` in SQL.  You can add as many fields as you wish, e.g.

```
await Asset.find({_id:ID},{model:true, status:true}).then((assets)=>{
```

Note that `_id` is always automatically returned.  You can inhibit this as follows:

```
await Asset.find({_id:ID},{model:true, _id:false}).then((assets)=>{
```

Comment: Cool! This answer can solve my question. Thank you very much!