# mongodb convert data to string. how to fix?

Tags: javascript, node.js, string, mongodb, callback

I want to get data from my database to work with variables.

Here is my database query:

```
db.progress.find({username:socket},function(err,res){
```

what do I get information on:

```
[ { _id: 61e180b54e0eea1454f8e5e6,
    username: 'user',
    exp: 0,
    fraction: 'undf'} ]
```

if i send a request

```
db.progress.find({username:socket},{exp:1},function(err,res){
```

then in return I will get

```
[ { _id: 61e180b54e0eea1454f8e5e6, exp: 0 } ]
```

how do i extract only 0 from the received data. I would like to do something like this.

```
var findprogress = function(socket,cb){
db.progress.find({username:socket},function(err,res){
cb(res.exp,res.fraction)
})
}



findprogress(socket,function(cb){
console.log(cb.exp)//0
console.log(cb.fraction)//undf
           })
```

but I don't know how to implement it correctly.

Comment: This is very very similar to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70712393/how-to-retrive-specific-data-from-mongodb/70712668#70712668   .   Propose to close as a dupe...?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`find` returns an array, so you will need to select the array element before accessing the field:

```
var findprogress = function(socket,cb){
  db.progress.find({username:socket},function(err,res){
    cb(res[0].exp,res[0].fraction)
  })
}
```

Comment: thank you very much. the only working option. if i enter cb(res[0].fraction) but if i enter cb(res[0].exp,res[0].fraction) and in another function I output console.log(cb.exp) console.log(cb.fraction) in that case i get undefined undefined... I'll try to make some callbacks. thanks for the help

Answer (score 1):

I recommend aggregate in this case so you can more easily manipulate your projected data. For example:

```
db.progress.aggregate([
{ $match: { username: socket } },
{ $project: { _id: 0, exp: 1 } }
])
```

This way you directly tell the query to not include the objectId, which is typically included by default.

Comment: Strictly within SO guidelines, `find()` with the second project arg is the more aligned answer to the question but yes -- in general, `aggregate()` is the new `find()` and queries that start with `find()` often end up needing the capabilities of `aggregate().`

Comment: if I use such a structure
    db.progress.aggregate({$match:{username:socket}},{$project:{_id:0,exp:1}},function(err,res)
    then at the output I get
  [ { exp: 0 } ]
  how do i remove everything but 0
  may be
  .toString()//[object Object]
  or
  .split(" } ]").shift().split("[ { exp: ").splice(1, 1).toString().shift());//is not a function

Answer (score 0):

Try to give `0` to _id:

```
db.progress.find({username:socket},{exp:1 , _id:0},function(err,res){
```

Comment: how to extract information from[ {  } ]